# GridView not encoding values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a DevExpress grid view that is bound to data, some of the collumns have  text including apostrophes represented as `&#39;`

In my GridView however, this text is not converted to `'` and instead displays the representation to the user.

Elsewhere on my page, such as text boxes, this is represented appropriately.

How can I force my GridView to encode these characters the same as other controls?

Comment: Please see the document here https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_EncodeHtmltopic which states "This member supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and cannot be used directly from your code."

Comment: Okay, but how do I get the grid column to display the correct symbol?

Comment: I think, I misunderstood "cannot be used directly from your code" statement as following answer seems working.
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q372430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I created a method in my cs which converted the value into a decoded string,

```
public string FormatHTML(object myStringObject)
{
    string myString = Convert.ToString(myStringObject);

    return Server.HtmlDecode(myString);
}
```

Then using in the DataGrid, I called this method for each column:

```
<dx:GridViewDataColumn Visible="true" VisibleIndex="10">
    <DataItemTemplate>    
       <%# FormatHTML(Eval("QuestionText")) %>
    </DataItemTemplate>
 </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```